# Generic repository and generic context for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, generics, .net-core, mongorepository

I have try to implement an generic repository and generic context to be use with mongodb. 
The problem that i encoured is that i receive the following error message:

[Unable to resolve service for type 'CommonLibrary.Database.GenericContext`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q1lQ.png)

Here is my configure service method from startup class:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<Settings>(
            options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDb:ConnectionString").Value;
                options.Database = Configuration.GetSection("MongoDb:Database").Value;
            });

        services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericContext<>), typeof(GenericContext<>));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    }
```

My generic context class:

```
public class GenericContext<T> : IGenericContext<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase db;
    public GenericContext(IOptions<Settings> options)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(options.Value.ConnectionString);
        db = client.GetDatabase(options.Value.Database);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<T> Entities => db.GetCollection<T>("Entities");
}
```

My generic repository class:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    private readonly GenericContext<T> _context;

    public GenericRepository(GenericContext<T> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _context
                        .Entities
                        .Find(_ => true)
                        .ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<T> GetById(string customerId)
    {
        FilterDefinition<T> filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(m => m.EntityId, customerId);

        return _context
                .Entities
                .Find(filter)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public async Task Create(T customer)
    {
        await _context.Entities.InsertOneAsync(customer);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Update(T customer)
    {
        ReplaceOneResult updateResult =
            await _context
                    .Entities
                    .ReplaceOneAsync(
                        filter: g => g.Id == customer.Id,
                        replacement: customer);

        return updateResult.IsAcknowledged
                && updateResult.ModifiedCount > 0;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(string entityId)
    {
        FilterDefinition<T> filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(m => m.EntityId, entityId);

        DeleteResult deleteResult = await _context
                                            .Entities
                                            .DeleteOneAsync(filter);

        return deleteResult.IsAcknowledged
            && deleteResult.DeletedCount > 0;
    }
}
```

My base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement]
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

And my derived Customer class:

```
public class Customer : BaseClass
{
    [BsonElement]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have any idea why my generic repository cannot be instantiated? It seems that is a problem with GenericContext, but i don't see where.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem in my generic repository i was injecting the class instead of interface:

```
public GenericRepository(GenericContext<T> context)
```